# Create random numbers in Sudoku JFormattedTextfield

Tags: java, swing, random, generator, sudoku

> Iam trying to Code a Sudoku Game with Swing. Iam new in Coding. The
> surface is ready but i dont know how to program the random numbers in
> the JFormattedTextfields. Maybe someone has an explanation and can help me to
> understand. I post the whole Code because i dont know what u need to help me...
> I only find Array things in the internet. I made it like that before but i cant make it beautiful with the inner lines so i did 3x3 textfields on a panel. And 3x3panels on a big panel.

```
 public class Sudokuu {
    public JFrame frame;

    private void buildGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("Sudoku");
        frame.setSize(1600, 1000);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel buttonpanel = new JPanel();

//      

        JButton one = new JButton("One Step");
        one.setFont(new Font("Bell MT", Font.BOLD, 20));
        one.setBackground(new Color(233, 242, 240));

        JButton easy = new JButton("Easy");
        easy.setFont(new Font("Bell MT", Font.BOLD, 20));
        easy.setBackground(new Color(233, 242, 240));

        JButton medium = new JButton("Medium");
        medium.setFont(new Font("Bell MT", Font.BOLD, 20));
        medium.setBackground(new Color(233, 242, 240));

        JButton hard = new JButton("Hard");
        hard.setFont(new Font("Bell MT", Font.BOLD, 20));
        hard.setBackground(new Color(233, 242, 240));

        buttonpanel.add(one);
        buttonpanel.add(easy);
        buttonpanel.add(medium);
        buttonpanel.add(hard);

//Sudoku 3x3 Feld
        {
            JPanel sudokufield = new JPanel();
            sudokufield.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
            sudokufield.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
            sudokufield.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black,3));

            for (int x = 0; x <= 2; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y <= 2; y++) {
                    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
                    NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(format);
                    formatter.setValueClass(Integer.class);
                    formatter.setMinimum(1);
                    formatter.setMaximum(9);
                    formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false); // eine Zahl erlaubt aber nicht löschen
                    formatter.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);

                    JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
//                  textField.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(1));
                    textField.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
                    textField.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 50));

                    textField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
                    textField.setBackground(new Color(213, 237, 236));

                    sudokufield.add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    sudokufield.add(buttonpanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
                }
            }

//          Sudoku 3x3 Feld 1
            {
                JPanel sudokufield1 = new JPanel();
                sudokufield1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
                sudokufield1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
                sudokufield1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black,3));
                for (int z = 0; z <= 2; z++) {
                    for (int u = 0; u <= 2; u++) {
                        NumberFormat format1 = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
                        NumberFormatter formatter1 = new NumberFormatter(format1);
                        formatter1.setValueClass(Integer.class);
                        formatter1.setMinimum(1);
                        formatter1.setMaximum(9);
                        formatter1.setAllowsInvalid(false); // eine Zahl erlaubt aber nicht löschen
                        formatter1.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);

                        JFormattedTextField textField1 = new JFormattedTextField(formatter1);
//                      textField1.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(1));
                        textField1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
                        textField1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 50));
                        textField1.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
                        textField1.setBackground(new Color(213, 237, 236));

                        sudokufield1.add(textField1);
                    }
                }

//              Sudokufield 3x3 2

                {
                    JPanel sudokufield2 = new JPanel();
                    sudokufield2.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
                    sudokufield2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
                    sudokufield2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black,3));
                    for (int a = 0; a <= 2; a++) {
                        for (int e = 0; e <= 2; e++) {
                            NumberFormat format2 = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
                            NumberFormatter formatter2 = new NumberFormatter(format2);
                            formatter2.setValueClass(Integer.class);
                            formatter2.setMinimum(1);
                            formatter2.setMaximum(9);
                            formatter2.setAllowsInvalid(false); // eine Zahl erlaubt aber nicht löschen
                            formatter2.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);

                            JFormattedTextField textField2 = new JFormattedTextField(formatter2);
//                          textField2.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(1));
                            textField2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
                            textField2.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 50));
                            textField2.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
                            textField2.setBackground(new Color(213, 237, 236));

                            sudokufield2.add(textField2);
                        }
                    }

//                  Sudokufield 3x3 3

                    {
                        JPanel sudokufield3 = new JPanel();
                        sudokufield3.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
                        sudokufield3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
                        sudokufield3.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black,3));
                        for (int b = 0; b <= 2; b++) {
                            for (int c = 0; c <= 2; c++) {
                                NumberFormat format3 = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
                                NumberFormatter formatter3 = new NumberFormatter(format3);
                                formatter3.setValueClass(Integer.class);
                                formatter3.setMinimum(1);
                                formatter3.setMaximum(9);
                                formatter3.setAllowsInvalid(false); // eine Zahl erlaubt aber nicht löschen
                                formatter3.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);

                                JFormattedTextField textField3 = new JFormattedTextField(formatter3);
//                              textField3.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(1));
                                textField3.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
                                textField3.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 50));
                                textField3.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
                                textField3.setBackground(new Color(213, 237, 236));

                                sudokufield3.add(textField3);
                            }
                        }

//                                      Sudokufield 3x3 4
                        {
                            JPanel sudokufield4 = new JPanel();
                            sudokufield4.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
                            sudokufield4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
                            sudokufield4.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black,3));
                            for (int d = 0; d <= 2; d++) {
                                for (int f = 0; f <= 2; f++) {
                                    NumberFormat format4 = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
                                    NumberFormatter formatter4 = new NumberFormatter(format4);
                                    formatter4.setValueClass(Integer.class);
                                    formatter4.setMinimum(1);
                                    formatter4.setMaximum(9);
                                    formatter4.setAllowsInvalid(false); // eine Zahl erlaubt aber nicht
                                                                        // löschen
                                    formatter4.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);

                                    JFormattedTextField textField4 = new JFormattedTextField(formatter4);
//                                  textField4.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(1));
                                    textField4.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
                                    textField4.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 50));
                                    textField4.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
                                    textField4.setBackground(new Color(213, 237, 236));

                                    sudokufield4.add(textField4, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                                }
                            }

//                                      Sudokufield 3x3 5
                            {
                                JPanel sudokufield5 = new JPanel();
                                sudokufield5.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
                                sudokufield5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
                                sudokufield5.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black,3));
                                for (int g = 0; g <= 2; g++) {
                                    for (int h = 0; h <= 2; h++) {
                                        NumberFormat format5 = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
                                        NumberFormatter formatter5 = new NumberFormatter(format5);
                                        formatter5.setValueClass(Integer.class);
                                        formatter5.setMinimum(1);
                                        formatter5.setMaximum(9);
                                        formatter5.setAllowsInvalid(false); // eine Zahl erlaubt
                                                                            // aber nicht löschen
                                        formatter5.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);

                                        JFormattedTextField textField5 = new JFormattedTextField(formatter5);
//                                      textField5.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(1));
                                        textField5.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
                                        textField5.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 50));
                                        textField5.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
                                        textField5.setBackground(new Color(213, 237, 236));

                                        sudokufield5.add(textField5, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                                    }
                                }

//                                                      Sudokufield 3x3 6
                                {
                                    JPanel sudokufield6 = new JPanel();
                                    sudokufield6.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
                                    sudokufield6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
                                    sudokufield6.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black,3));
                                    for (int g = 0; g <= 2; g++) {
                                        for (int h = 0; h <= 2; h++) {
                                            NumberFormat format6 = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
                                            NumberFormatter formatter6 = new NumberFormatter(format6);
                                            formatter6.setValueClass(Integer.class);
                                            formatter6.setMinimum(1);
                                            formatter6.setMaximum(9);
                                            formatter6.setAllowsInvalid(false); // eine Zahl erlaubt
                                                                                // aber nicht löschen
                                            formatter6.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);

                                            JFormattedTextField textField6 = new JFormattedTextField(formatter6);
//                                          textField6.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(1));
                                            textField6.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
                                            textField6.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 50));
                                            textField6.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
                                            textField6.setBackground(new Color(213, 237, 236));

                                            sudokufield6.add(textField6, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                                        }
                                    }

//                                                          Sudokufield 3x3 7
                                    {
                                        JPanel sudokufield7 = new JPanel();
                                        sudokufield7.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
                                        sudokufield7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
                                        sudokufield7.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black,3));
                                        for (int g = 0; g <= 2; g++) {
                                            for (int h = 0; h <= 2; h++) {
                                                NumberFormat format7 = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
                                                NumberFormatter formatter7 = new NumberFormatter(format7);
                                                formatter7.setValueClass(Integer.class);
                                                formatter7.setMinimum(1);
                                                formatter7.setMaximum(9);
                                                formatter7.setAllowsInvalid(false); // eine Zahl erlaubt
                                                                                    // aber nicht löschen
                                                formatter7.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);

                                                JFormattedTextField textField7 = new JFormattedTextField(formatter7);
//                                              textField7.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(1));
                                                textField7.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
                                                textField7.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 50));
                                                textField7.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
                                                textField7.setBackground(new Color(213, 237, 236));

                                                sudokufield7.add(textField7, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                                            }
                                        }
//                                                              Sudokufield 3x3 8
                                        {
                                            JPanel sudokufield8 = new JPanel();
                                            sudokufield8.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
                                            sudokufield8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
                                            sudokufield8.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black,3));
                                            for (int g = 0; g <= 2; g++) {
                                                for (int h = 0; h <= 2; h++) {
                                                    NumberFormat format8 = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
                                                    NumberFormatter formatter8 = new NumberFormatter(format8);
                                                    formatter8.setValueClass(Integer.class);
                                                    formatter8.setMinimum(1);
                                                    formatter8.setMaximum(9);
                                                    formatter8.setAllowsInvalid(false); // eine Zahl erlaubt
                                                                                        // aber nicht löschen
                                                    formatter8.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);

                                                    JFormattedTextField textField8 = new JFormattedTextField(
                                                            formatter8);
//                                                  textField8.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(1));
                                                    textField8.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
                                                    textField8.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 50));
                                                    textField8.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
                                                    textField8.setBackground(new Color(213, 237, 236));

                                                    sudokufield8.add(textField8, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                                                }
                                            }
//                                                                  Sudokufield 3x3 9
                                            {
                                                JPanel sudokufield9 = new JPanel();
                                                sudokufield9.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
                                                sudokufield9.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
                                                sudokufield9.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black,3));
                                                for (int g = 0; g <= 2; g++) {
                                                    for (int h = 0; h <= 2; h++) {
                                                        NumberFormat format9 = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
                                                        NumberFormatter formatter9 = new NumberFormatter(format9);
                                                        formatter9.setValueClass(Integer.class);
                                                        formatter9.setMinimum(1);
                                                        formatter9.setMaximum(9);
                                                        formatter9.setAllowsInvalid(false); // eine Zahl erlaubt
                                                                                            // aber nicht löschen
                                                        formatter9.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);

                                                        JFormattedTextField textField9 = new JFormattedTextField(
                                                                formatter9);
//                                                      textField9.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(1));
                                                        textField9.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
                                                        textField9.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 50));
                                                        textField9.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
                                                        textField9.setBackground(new Color(213, 237, 236));

                                                        sudokufield9.add(textField9, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                JPanel bigSudoku = new JPanel();
                                                bigSudoku.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
                                                bigSudoku.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
                                                bigSudoku.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black,3));

                                                bigSudoku.add(sudokufield);
                                                bigSudoku.add(sudokufield1);
                                                bigSudoku.add(sudokufield2);
                                                bigSudoku.add(sudokufield3);
                                                bigSudoku.add(sudokufield4);
                                                bigSudoku.add(sudokufield5);
                                                bigSudoku.add(sudokufield6);
                                                bigSudoku.add(sudokufield7);
                                                bigSudoku.add(sudokufield8);
                                                bigSudoku.add(sudokufield9);

                                                frame.add(bigSudoku, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                                                frame.add(buttonpanel);
//          frame.add(sudokufield,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                                                frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, buttonpanel);
                                                frame.getContentPane().add(sudokufield);
                                                frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, bigSudoku);

                                                frame.pack();
                                                frame.setVisible(true);
                                                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Sudoku Generator Algorithm](https://www.101computing.net/sudoku-generator-algorithm/)  Break up your monolith code into methods.

Comment: @gilbert le blanc Could you tell  me please how to break it up into methods? I found that link too but i dont know how to implement those things because i have different int with g,h,d,f do u know what i mean?

Answer (score 0):

I broke up your monolithic code into methods.

A method is a block of code that only runs when it is called.  You can pass data, known as parameters, into a method.  Methods are used to perform certain actions, and they are also known as functions.  Why use methods? To reuse code: define the code once, and use it many times.

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter;

public class SudokuGenerator implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SudokuGenerator());
    }

    private final Color backgroundColor1, backgroundColor2;

    private final Font sudokuFont, textFont;

    private JPanel[] sudokuFieldPanel;

    public SudokuGenerator() {
        this.sudokuFont = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 50);
        this.textFont = new Font("Bell MT", Font.BOLD, 20);
        this.backgroundColor1 = new Color(233, 242, 240);
        this.backgroundColor2 = new Color(213, 237, 236);
        this.sudokuFieldPanel = new JPanel[9];
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sudoku");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel buttonpanel = createButtonPanel();
        frame.add(buttonpanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel bigSudoku = createLargeSudoku();
        frame.add(bigSudoku, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createLargeSudoku() {
        for (int index = 0; index < 9; index++) {
            sudokuFieldPanel[index] = create3x3SudokuPanel();
        }

        return createSudokuPanel(sudokuFieldPanel);
    }

    private JPanel createSudokuPanel(JPanel[] sudokuFieldPanel) {
        JPanel bigSudoku = new JPanel();
        bigSudoku.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        bigSudoku.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        bigSudoku.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 3));

        for (int index = 0; index < sudokuFieldPanel.length; index++) {
            bigSudoku.add(sudokuFieldPanel[index]);
        }

        return bigSudoku;
    }

    private JPanel create3x3SudokuPanel() {
        JPanel sudokuPanel = new JPanel();
        sudokuPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        sudokuPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        sudokuPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 3));

        for (int x = 0; x <= 2; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y <= 2; y++) {
                createSudokuJFormattedTextField(sudokuPanel, createFormatter());
            }
        }

        return sudokuPanel;
    }

    private void createSudokuJFormattedTextField(JPanel sudokufield,
            NumberFormatter formatter) {
        JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        textField.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
        textField.setFont(sudokuFont);
        textField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        textField.setBackground(backgroundColor2);

        sudokufield.add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private NumberFormatter createFormatter() {
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
        NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(format);
        formatter.setValueClass(Integer.class);
        formatter.setMinimum(1);
        formatter.setMaximum(9);
        formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
        formatter.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);

        return formatter;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel buttonpanel = new JPanel();

        JButton one = new JButton("One Step");
        one.setFont(textFont);
        one.setBackground(backgroundColor1);

        JButton easy = new JButton("Easy");
        easy.setFont(textFont);
        easy.setBackground(backgroundColor1);

        JButton medium = new JButton("Medium");
        medium.setFont(textFont);
        medium.setBackground(backgroundColor1);

        JButton hard = new JButton("Hard");
        hard.setFont(textFont);
        hard.setBackground(backgroundColor1);

        buttonpanel.add(one);
        buttonpanel.add(easy);
        buttonpanel.add(medium);
        buttonpanel.add(hard);

        return buttonpanel;
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow thank u...but where u call the Methods? i know that as Method() ..can u explain me why always return the things?

Comment: @Miezemi: Each field or variable is local to a method unless it's a class field or variable.  Each method returns one field or variable.  This minimizes the number of class fields or variables.